# Computational pitfalls of calling multiple functions from within a function

Tags: python

I use the Python programming language extensively in my research and have a few publications that required the submission of my code base. I do mostly nearest-neighbours type data mining at the moment. I am starting to worry about writing the best possible code as others are beginning to use my code. At the moment, I am iterating over a large number of directories (~100,000) and use a single main() function to sequentially call a series of small functions that each perform an individual task:

```
import os
# ... other libs

def my_function_A():
    print('my function A')

def my_function_B():
    print('my function B')

def my_function_C():
    print('my function C')

# ... 40 or more such functions

def main():
    my_function_A() # do task a
    my_function_B() # do task b
    my_function_C() # do task c
    # ....
    return result

for dirs in os.listdir(dir_to_iterate_over):
    result = main()
    # iterate over many directories
```

My senior supervisor expects all functions to perform at most one task but here I am calling a main function that's performing a slew of tasks. I am interested (and slightly concerned) about how this approach affects overall program performance (i.e. what effects this has on dynamic stack allocation, etc.)

Comment: Impossible really to comment on your actual program. Calling multiple functions from another function is normal. Nobody can give you any concrete advice here with such vague information. I'm voting to close.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I agree, but I added some vague recommendations in an answer :). Maybe that helps David.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What your senior supervisor means is not that you cannot have a main function which call a slew of other functions. In this regard, the main function also "does only one thing", namely call out to the other functions which actually does the real work of the program.

When it comes to performance, the delegation of code between functions is not at all where you should be focusing your worries. Actually, writing badly structured code with very few functions will yield *better* performance in Python, because function calls are actually quite expensive. Still, you should *not* take this to mean that you should try to keep the number of functions low. The structure of your code into functions (and classes, modules, etc.) should be determined only by your mental model of the program, not performance concerns. For that, focus on the algorithms and implementations thereof in the actual "worker" functions.

Comment: This is the sort of answer I was looking for. And yes, I have noticed that too. I used to write very low level code (taking advantage of Python's built ins) and noticed a significant speed reduction when I started using higher level libraries such as Pandas, despite how much easier Pandas made my work.

Comment: jmd_dk I think your answer is perfectly fine, except for the "quite expensive" term. which is misleading for OP and other readers. Compared to what? If the inner function block is very very fast it will have some, otherwise it may be negligible (the most common, the functions do the work right?)  You should edit your answer. Both of you please, read the accepted answer where it reads "in a nutshell:" here https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/318055/how-much-do-function-calls-impact-performance. Measure is the answer.

Answer (score 1):

High-level part of the question:

Calling functions to perform tasks is what we do all the time in programing. That's a structured programming approach. Divide a big problem into smaller, simpler tasks. Solve the big problem by solving all the smaller ones.

Now, this is a high-level approach to solving problems, and also a way to manage complexity while coding the solution. Whether the simpler tasks are highly focused and almost one-step blocks, or more elaborated recipes is much like a personal choice of the coder. Make it very granular and it is good for code readability by humans (code maintenance) and for adding features in small steps (manage complexity again). It may also look like adding overhead because you are wrapping very small blocks of code in a repeated pattern. It is overhead, but at these stage we do not worry with performance but with the quality of the code base (in terms of readability, testability, and overall architecture), and by the way, in having a solution that actually works.

Low-level part of the question:

Next if you find that your code has poor performance (and you have to quantify what that is), you have to measure or profile the code.

Insert time measurements in specific places of the code to find where most of execution time is spent, and then try to change/optimize that parts.

Your concerns about stack allocation are pretty low-level concerns, don't mix that with high-level questions like overall code organization.

In summary:

Write the solution first, leave optimzation to a later time, and make it by measuring, always.

As an architetural tip, if you find that you are calling dozens of functions (in a serial way), try to find related concerns between them and try to partition the system by grouping some of those related functions in modules or classes, to give some kind of spatial structure to the code, otherwise it's structure will look like a pile (or pancake) and that's also a poor thing to manage mentally.

Comment: Yes, I have typically been using a divide-and-conquer approach almost exclusively until I started noticing the cost of function calls. The time measurement suggestion has been helpful. I started using time.time() intervals everywhere to get a general idea of where my program is bottlenecking.

Comment: @David check my comment on the other answer. Also by function calls I mean user defined defs, not library functions. Python is performant when using built-in types and functions whose implementation is in C, and slower if using library functions written in Python (most of the standard python library and those third-party modules we install). In particular the use of user-defined objects will add some overhead, due to the creation of associated internal dicts for the object members.